# Regex matching wrong

Tags: regex

My current regex matches the first number `703205749` because it finds the matching number inside the string, but how can I skip the number if it doesn't start with a specific number/letter.

```
regex = (2|7|8|1)\d{7,12}

string = 'first number 32703205749, second number 714525596'
```

Should match only `714525596`

Comment: Perhaps, you could use the word-boundary matcher here, `\b`.

Comment: `\b[1278]\d{7,12}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use starting `^` and ending `$` anchors to denote the bounds of the number.  Also, your alternation of starting first digits might be easier to read as a character class.  Putting all this together we can try:

```
^[2781]\d{7,12}$
```

Or, if you want to match the entire number inside a larger string, surround it by word boundaries:

```
\b[2781]\d{7,12}\b
```

Comment: The first one does not work. Using ` \b` solution works great.